# Android XML Request doesn't parse '+' plus sign

Tags: android, xml

I am querying Yahoo Finance for stock quotes, the format is as follows:

[website]?s=[stock ticker]+[stock ticker]..... etc

It works fine individually but when I add the + and do two at a time, the CSV returned says "Missing Format Variable". I've tried %2B but no luck.

The surrounding code is as follows

```
URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDGBP=X+USDEUR=X&amp;f=l1");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
String[] yahooRateInfo = new BufferedReader(isr).readLine().split(",");
Double rateGBP = Double.parseDouble(yahooRateInfo[0]);
Double rateEUR = Double.parseDouble(yahooRateInfo[1]);
```

Thanks in advance

Dre

Comment: Show us the code where you're calling this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=USDGBP=X+USDEUR=X&f=l1");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
BufferedReader yahooRateInfo = new BufferedReader(isr);
try {
Double rateGBP = Double.parseDouble(yahooRateInfo.readLine());
Double rateEUR = Double.parseDouble(yahooRateInfo.readLine());
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
   Log.d(TAG, "error parsing rates",e);
}
```

It does not fail because of the '+' sign, but of the second get-parameter which is malformed.

Comment: Although that URL does return a value, it only returns the first value. i.e. 0.1234 where it should return 0.1234,0.5678.

Comment: Did you see the second row? Isn't this the second value you'r looking for?

Comment: The second row shows up when I do it via desktop but doesn't come out on Android